# CentOS won't boot when disk is removed

Tags: linux, centos, mount, systemctl

In my system I have a boot drive (xfs) and a RAID (ext4).  The RAID is `/dev/sda` so I have added that in fstab to auto-mount at startup.

```
/dev/sda        /mnt/RAID       ext4    defaults    0 0
```

Today I destroyed the RAID and turned it into a JBOD, which means `sda1` is now a single disk without no filesystem.  This caused the system to boot into emergency mode with an error that it can't find an ext4 filesystem on sda.  Eventually I fixed it by removing the line from fstab, removing the mount unit from `/run/systemd/generator`, and running `systemctl daemon-reload`.

My question:  Is there an easier way?  For a system that may have drives removed frequently, this is too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior for fstab entries. To quietly skip an entry when the device is not present, mark it with the `nofail` fstab option.